The Lost Continents of Atlantis and Mu reappear: Disruption to Transport
In a single event, the lost continents of Atlantis and Mu arise from the deeps over the course of about half an hour, accompanied by a low-magnitude earthquake felt worldwide.
For the purpose of this question (though in my story they are not so simple), let us assume that both Atlantis and Mu are effectively circular landmasses with diameters of 2,000 km, and that their points of appearance correspond to their centre.  Each has a ring of mountains around their centre as high as the Himalayas and 1,000 km in diameter.
Atlantis appears at the Atlantic Pole of Inaccessibility, 24.1851°N 43.3704°W.
Mu appears at Point Nemo, the oceanic pole of inaccessibility, at  49.0273°S 123.4345°W.
My question is: How disruptive would the reappearance of these two continents would be to modern transportation?
Answers should include the potential for aircraft or ships to be lost during the reappearance event, and how long it would take the authorities and news media to provide warnings to shipping and the general public.
EDIT:

Sea levels do not change as a result.  There are no tsunamis.

I am not concerned with government responses beyond the timing of warnings to operators of vessels or aircraft already in the affected areas.


Edit 2:
To be clearer, I am interested in the numbers of vessels that may be damaged or lost as a result of this occurence, and the timeline for public awareness of this event.
I am not interested in the potential political or climatic ramifications.  Anything that happens more than 12 hours after global public awareness of the event is out of scope.

Why would any aircraft be lost? Standard cruising altitude is 10,000+ meters, already higher than the Himalayas. And if it takes a half hour for these continents to emerge (with their absolutely magical lack of impact on the air and water around them), that seems plenty of time for even the most inattentive pilots to make any necessary adjustments.

@JayMcEh Probably correct about planes, but what about ships?  I'd ask about road vehicles too, if there were any way that any could be anywhere near there.

A few ships will be lost. Somewhere in the low dozens at absolute most. You can find interactive maps showing shipping traffic (random example: https://www.vox.com/2016/4/25/11503152/shipping-routes-map). Pause at any given moment, overlay the circles at your points, and you'll see there really aren't all that many ships in the space at any one time. It'll be remarkably expensive and potentially disruptive to a few key industries relying on those specific ships, but not globally notable to shipping at large.

Any road vehicles in those areas at that time will probably be very grateful for the sudden appearance of land underneath them, although it's probably not economically significant and would in fact be only the second most confusing thing to happen to the drivers that day.

The Atlantic Pole of Inaccessibility is in the middle of the artic. What happens to the several kilometer thick icesheat that is currently floating there?

I'm struggling with the concept of a science-based question about events that evidently are deeply magical.  Australia-size continents with kilometers-high mountains arise from the ocean?  In minutes?  With no sea level change, no tsunamis, nothing but a gentle rumble anywhere?

@JohnBollinger, there's no problem with calculating the scientific effects from a magical cause.

This is kind of an odd question but I'll take a crack at answering it in the most straight forward way I know how.
By drawing a 2000km circle in the middle of the Atlantic and counting how many ships are in it.

Looks like Atlantis takes out around 100 ships if it appears in the middle of the day
(I realize its not at exactly 24.1851°N 43.3704°W, 3d projections on 2d surfaces are weird, so give or take 20-30 ships)
And the same for point nemo

Mu might take out a couple of research vessels and some fool lost on a yacht.
Zero planes are getting even remotely damaged by either island, planes flying over the Atlantic and Pacific are cruising at much higher altitudes than the Himalayas.
As for response time? Pretty damn fast.
I'm going off the basis that underneath each island its connected to the surrounding sea floor, the Atlantic has an average depth of around 3.6km, you say in a comment that each island rises in half an hour to its final height with the mountain tops reaching 8,8km (The Himalayas) for a combined height of 12.4km rising in the span of 30 minutes. Or 410m per minute.
There is no way in hell ships aren't going to notice parts of the ocean floor decreasing in depth by a kilometer in 3 minutes. Anything with sonar in that area is already sending messages up the chain of command that something is wrong.
Within 5 minutes NOAA is losing their minds because DART and Tsunami Warning Centers are indicating a large portion of the Atlantic/Pacific sea floor is moving upwards very fast.
Earthquake warnings are going out to every country bordering the Atlantic/Pacific to prepare for an apocalyptic seismic event.
In under 10 minutes, mountains have started jutting out of the ocean, by this point every major government is monitoring the situation in whatever way they can. I'd imagine most available weather satellites over the Atlantic/Pacific have captured something and intelligence agencies likely have high resolution satellite images of each new island within minutes.
410m per minute is very fast when it comes to changes in topography, especially changes that are 2000km wide. Even with very early warnings, I'd say half the ships wouldn't have time to divert off course far enough to escape the islands. But certainly once NOAA is involved, any ships in the Atlantic would be diverted pretty fast so I doubt any other ships would be lost unless they were sailing with zero communication equipment and were literally blind.
By the time Atlantis and Mu have risen halfway, the entire world would be on alert and images of these islands would be circulating in every major government and possibly to the media.

Can you think of any reason why this event might not be communicated to the media straight away?

Well, they probably would but it wouldn't be "Atlantis just appeared out of nowhere", it would be "Earthquake/Tsunami event alert issued by {insert government agency}". Do you remember the Japan 2011 earthquake? Broadcasters displayed a warning pretty fast after the earthquake was detected.
It'd actually be very unlikely if some sort of warning wasn't sent out almost immediately. That would defeat the point of early warning systems.

@MontyWild Unless the islands were literally invisible on every system, some sort of warning will go out to prepare for a disaster. But again, its highly unlikely they'd outright say it was an Island, it would be some sort of natural disaster.

Answer: minimal disruption in the south, huge disruption in the north. The appearance of a new continent in the North Atlantic would disrupt the busiest sea lane routes in the world i.e North America to Europe due to the sudden need for all shipping to now take long circuitous voyages around the new continent. Air routes would be disrupted temporarily while adjusting for the changes in flight altitude required. Meanwhile shipping routes in the South Pacific and to a lesser extent air routes would only suffer relatively minor disruption overall compared to the northern hemisphere because the location of point Nemo would basically only effect flights to and from Australia South America etc
Once everyone realized there were no major geological repercussions i.e. no massive tsunami's (which there would be) no sunlight blotting volcanic eruptions (which there would be) and no catastrophic changes in sea levels (which there would be) and the minor issue of Gulf Stream having to radically change course? Shipping would adjust in relatively short order although the greatly increased cost of shipping goods (due to the much longer voyage times) would lead to a rise in global inflation.
There would also huge disruption to communications because a large number of transatlantic sub sea optical cables which would need to be replaced at great expense. Again the effect would be much less in the south given few cables pass through the relevant zone there.
Russia, America, Canada and the rest of Europe would probably also start a massive war over who 'owns' Atlantis and everyone would want to claim a piece. Same would happen in the South with China making a claim and everyone else trying to grab a share of Mu before it was too late.
EDIT: It has been pointed out I referred incorrectly to the Arctic POI instead of the Atlantic POI. That dramatically changes the answer re; disruption to sea lanes etc in the northern hemisphere. The answer remains largely unchanged int he southern hemisphere.

Note that Atlantis appears in the Atlantic POI, not the Arctic POI. There would probably rather a few disruptions at Atlantis!

Can you account for the numbers of losses of aircraft and ships in each event, as well as the timeline of public awareness of the incidents?

@MontyWild that depends on how sudden they appear?!

@Trish, sentence 1: In a single event, the lost continents of Atlantis and Mu arise from the deeps over the course of about half an hour, accompanied by a low-magnitude earthquake felt worldwide.

The only transoceanic cables that could potentially be disrupted are Nuvem and Seabras-1 in the north atlantic.  See https://www.submarinecablemap.com/

Another thing that would disrupt transport, would be that ships and planes would be ordered away from Atlantis and Mu for legal reasons, until the political situation is solved. Effectively, despite not being countries yet, Atlantis and Mu would be treated as if they had sovereign airspace and territorial waters,  and would be off-limits to civilian craft, lest they unbalance the political situation and cause WW3 (like say, a Brazilian container ship accidentally beaching itself on Mu and thus, unintentionally claiming the new land for Brazil).

@GoingDurden That's rather a longer timescale than I was interested in.  My immediate interest is in transport losses and timeline to public notice of the change.

Strong disagreement on the level of disruption that Atlantis would cause. Draw the radius on a map and compare to shipping charts. It's a minor annoyance at most (aside from the political and geological ramifications which you are completely right about, but we're apparently supposed to disregard).

I believe that the most disruption to traffic will come from the major changes to weather that such a new continent will cause. First off, rock quickly lifted up that high will be quite hot and will give off a lot of steam causing a high-pressure area. Second, the weather patterns will change concentrating storms in new areas. New York will get hit by hurricanes.

@DavidR I should have said, Atl;antis and Mu will be icy cold, not hot.

@MontyWild while they may eventually be icy cold, at first the rock will be the temperature it was while deep in the earth. Mountains as high as the Himalayas will have raised up from as much as 7 km deep. Those rocks will be as hot as 150 - 200 degrees C. (30C /km) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geothermal_gradient  It will take a while to cool off the rocks. (Hot springs in the Olympic Mountains are believed to be due to how fast those mountains were raised.)

Secondly, the faults on which you are raising the mountains will generate enough friction to melt rock. That is how you get to do the raising without huge earthquakes.

@DavidR there is magic involved in getting the continents in place, it's not a geological event.  The question is science based because I'm asking about what follows.

@Monty Wild. While the arrival and rise of the two new continents might 'magical' their impact on climate, ocean currents, civilization and geopolitics AFTER they are in place will not be.

@Mon I agree entirely. However, I am only concerned with the time it takes for it to appear on the news, and what vessels might be grounded.

I wonder if any Internet Atlantic cables would be affected by such a landmass eruption. If yes, it'll be seriously felt by ISPs that arrange intercontinental traffic, down to causing warfare out of mere break-up of direct connection between USA and Europe.

@Vesper If you've ever been on a cable laying ship (I had the privilege) or seen a documentary on the industry you'd see they're not exactly 'stretchy' by which I means there ability to flex under strain is minimal.  For example the Tonga underwater volcanic eruption a few years ago cause an underwater mud slide that buried (and snapped) cables in the vicinity. So in this scenario? There's literally no way they could adjust to the vertical strain imposed by a continent rising under them.

@Mon I meant whether the landmass would be close enough to those cables to affect them, not that whether they would break if affected, the latter is expected. I'm not familiar with their rough layout in the Atlantic, so I can't say if they are laid so that the continent rise circle intersects them, but if it does, they will break.

Hundreds of ships lost, one major and several minor shipping lanes will require significantly longer routes.
The image below represents the current tracking information of ships in the Atlantic. A rough estimate of the number of ships which will end up grounded on the new 2000 km diameter continent is about 200. The information of a new continent appearing will be almost instantaneous, and would be reported by news agencies within minutes, although it may be a matter of hours to get that information to some affected ships without modern satellite communications. There is only one major shipping lane which will be significantly impacted. That lane goes from the straight of Gibraltar to the Panama Canal. Other minor lanes will also be impacted.

The situation in the pacific will be far less impactful, only an estimated 10-30 ships would be grounded by the new continent, based on the corresponding tracking information for the Pacific. No major lanes will be affected, only some very minor ones, and the news situation will be similar to that in the Atlantic.

Flights will be largely unaffected by what lies beneath them, except for the change in the wind patterns, but we're ignoring the climate impacts for the purpose of this question. There will also be an increased demand for flights going over these new continents filled with people who want to see (or visit when that becomes an option).

As far as aircraft are concerned, based on FlightAware's live tracking map; Atlantis is almost certainly going to cause disruption to a fair number of flights, maybe as many as ten could be trapped in the rising mountains and destroyed at any given time, if they are below their usual cruising altitude for any reason. In the case of Mu you would be unfortunate to effect even one flight.
In the case of surface shipping MarineTraffic's live map leads me to believe that the case is similar, Atlantis will cause major disruption with the uplift of dozens of ships; Mu might capture one directly, maybe.
In short Atlantis will be detected immediately due to the possible lose of many lives the definite lose of many ships and possibly some planes. Mu on the other hand may be detected immediately, but it's kind of unlikely. Mu does however lie on the direct flight path between Santiago Chile and several destinations in both New Zealand and Australia, there are a number of passenger flights each day. Mu will be detected the day it emerges even if it doesn't come up under/into anyone directly.
I would expect preliminary warnings to air traffic and shipping will go out to the relevant entities while Atlantis was still emerging from the waves. These warnings won't do the vehicles already in the new continents' footprint much good but they should be able divert further shipping and aircraft from entering the danger zone. Mu could well emerge entirely unseen but will be noted and warnings issues within hours.
That's assuming the continents need to be encountered by the ships and/or aircraft affected, in reality both will show up almost as soon as they start to move due to their disruption of both undersea cables and sea-level monitoring/tsunami warning systems like DART and GLOSS that use deep sea buoy networks.

How about timeline to shipping warnings and public awareness?

@MontyWild Sorry I got engrossed in the part of the question I was already answering and missed that part. Sorted, I think, let me know if you want more details.

https://www.submarinecablemap.com/ seems to suggest that there are no cables in the way of Mu, and almost none near Atlantis... possibly only two.

As for tsunamis or sea-level changes, the continents show up by magic, and there won't be any noticeable effect... at least not immediately.

@MontyWild Huh I was sure there was a direct link from Wellington to Chile I stand corrected. Deep ocean buoys suddenly starting to rise into the air will be immediately noticeable, and DART has a cable to the seabed to measure wave height, that going slack is going to be very noticeable and notable before the land mass breaks the surface.

There are flights between Auckland and Santiago that should pass over Mu.

@MontyWild And Melbourne, that's why I put "Mu does however lie on the direct flight path between Santiago Chile and several destinations in both New Zealand and Australia, there are a number of passenger flights each day. Mu will be detected the day it emerges even if it doesn't come up under/into anyone directly." in my answer.
